# Switch not connecting to all computers

Tags: port, switch, configuration-management

I need help configuring a switch (Datacom DM4000).

It has 2 ports, one for management and one for console (obviously more 24 ports for normal use).

With a RJ-45 to serial cable I was able to configure the IP from the management port and **with a normal RJ-45 cable I could ping, access it with telnet and so on**.

The problem was that not all my computers could access the switch.

I have 4 computers:

1 - Desktop Dell Vostro with Ubuntu 15.04

2 - old PC with Ubuntu Server 16.04 and 2 network interface

3 - Notebook Dell Vostro with some ubuntu

4 - Notebook Lenovo Yoga 900 with Windows 10 and a USB ethernet

**The computers 1 and 3 can connect with no problem, the computers 2 and 4 can't!**

I tried with 3 different cables, **when I connect 1 or 3 the LED "Link/act" become on** and when I use the command "ethtool ethX" say it is on. But **when I connect to 4 or both network interfaces on 2 the LED stays off** and the ethtool says it has no link. I even tried to use wireshark to capture any packet but nothing arrived.

My computer 1 has a little bug (at least I think so) that when I connect the cable it get no IP, even though is configured with static IP (but the link/LED is on), so I have to reset the interface (the link/LED goes off and on) and then get the IP and I can connect.
All other computers are setup with static IP too.

Any ideia why this is happening?

The only thing in common that I can see is that both computers that work are from Dell, so maybe they have any different configuration but besides that nothing in common.

Any test that I can execute to try to see what the problem is?

The computer that I need the most to connect is 2 because it has two interfaces and I pretend to run several tests with it.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Providing more information:

Computer 1 ethtool connected to mgmt-eth:

```
sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Computer 2 ethtool connected to mgmt-eth: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajxyq.jpg

Computer 2 ethtool connected to console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdDsu.jpg

DM4000 configuration:  (running on computer 1)

```
DM4000(config-if-mgmt-eth)#show ip interface 
MGMT-ETH     172.20.0.3/20     

DM4000(config-if-mgmt-eth)#show interfaces status mgmt-eth
Information of Mgmt-Eth
 Configuration:
  Port admin:             Up
  Speed-duplex:           Auto
  Capabilities:           10M half, 10M full, 100M half, 100M full, TX/RX pause
 Current status:
  Link status:            Up
  Operation speed-duplex: 100M full
  Flow-control:           Disabled

DM4000(config-if-mgmt-eth)#show running-config
Building configuration...
!
! Board models in this configuration:
! Unit 1: ETH24GX H Series+L3
!
hostname DM4000
!
```

Comment: I believe you patch cords are faulty. Could you please use a *guaranteed* working Cat5e patch cord and report your experience with that?

Comment: I used! Two of these 3 cables I had just opened from the plastic bag that came other network gear. I have a cable test and all of them were perfect! I tried all 4 computers with all 3 cables, they all work on 1 and 3 and don't on 2 and 4.

Comment: Now could you confirm that these 2 and 4 could connect to some other gigabit-capable switch with these patch cords, and also post the current configuration of  DM4000 (as an edit to your question)?

Comment: What line card are you trying to connect to? ETH24GX? ETH24GXH?

Comment: Sure! I did that, when i plug in the console port (however can't connect) or in one of the 24 gigabit port the link goes up. However the two network interfaces on 2 are probably not gigabit but the USB adapter on 4 is gigabit (at least says in the product). But is that a problem? The current configuration on the switch I can only post it tomorrow, but I remember that it says that can connect to all kind of connections

Comment: Wait. Are you trying to connect to the management port and having trouble? Is your question only about connecting to the management port?

Comment: ETH24GX accord to the manual. Yes, my problem is only with the management port! I have two of these switchs and this happen on both. All ports work just fine, the problem is only in the management port with a few computers.

Comment: Can you show the status of a normal port? I have a theory.

Comment: Can you add the brand of 'old PC' and 'USB ethernet' as well?

Comment: The status you can see in the images in the edited post. The configuration is: Motherboard M2NPV-VM with built-in NIC / ADM Athlon 64 X2 5200+ / Plus a NIC ENLGA-1320 / Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bet is that the management port doesn't have [auto-MDIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface#Auto_MDI-X). If these computers also don't have auto-MDIX, you'll need a crossover cable to connect the two interfaces.

The port jacks are switch ports and are meant to connect to a device. The management jack *is* a device and is meant to connect to a switch port. Connecting a device to a device will only work if at least one device has auto-MDIX. Most devices do, but it seems you may have found some that don't.

Comment: It make sense! But the switch has MDIX, at least I think so. I could't find how to display the current configuration. But was able to set up. Under "config-if-mgmt-eth" has options to set up mdix in mode "normal" and "force-auto". I tried both and still couldn't get a link. I unfortunately don't have a crossover cable, but I'll try to find one and test it.

Comment: The switch ports probably habe auto-MDIX.. But you're not connecting to the switch, you're connecting to the management interface. The management interface is probably a "dumb" device.

Comment: I thought that the MDIX configuration was to the management interface, but if it is to the switch then that make complete sense why is not working! Well, I'll try with a crossover cable but thank you!!!